# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 200

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to get rid of this Exception?

```
public  class Obs2  {

int [] ary=new int[200];
int c=1,b,d,x,y,s,j,p,v=0;
int i=1;

public int find(int N){


    for(int a=2;a<100;a++)
    {  
        s=a;
        do
        {
            x=a/2;
            y=a%2;
            if(y==0)
            {
                a=x;
            }
       }while(y==0 && x!=1);
        if(y==0 && x==1) 
        {
            ary[v]=s;   //This is line 28
           ++v;
        }

        else if(y!=0 && a>2)
        {  

            do{
               j=a/3;
               c=a%3;
               a=j;
            }while(c==0 && j!=1);

            if(c==0 && j==1)
            {
                ary[v]=s;
                v++;
            }
        }

    } 

  return ary[N];
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Obs2 obs =new Obs2();
    System.out.print(obs.find(10));   //And this is line 56
} 

}
```

My output says that

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 200

at obs2.Obs2.find(Obs2.java:28)

at obs2.Obs2.main(Obs2.java:56)

Comment: How can you not go crazy with your your variable name `l`?! It looks like a `1`. lol.

Comment: What have you tried to get rid of the exception? Where are lines 28 and 56 in your code? (you may want to add // comments).

Comment: Change your variables name my eyes are bleeding.

Comment: They seems same but not. They are l and 1 as you know.

Comment: Before getting the index, check the length of the array.

Comment: the variable a is set to 1 in every iteration of the do..while loop.

Comment: Your array has 200 elements. Valid indices are 0 upto and including 199. Your program tries to access the array with index 200. This is an invalid index.

Comment: I changed variable name and showd the line 28, 56.

Comment: Actually my program tries to access the array with index 10. If you look at line 56 you will see that program sends 10 as a parameter to find(int N) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do

```
do
    {
        x=a/2;
        y=a%2;
        if(y==0)
        {
            a=x;
        }
    }while(y==0 && x!=1);
```

always x=1, y=0, a=1

and then in the if-else

```
if(y==0 && x==1)
{
    ary[v]=s;   //in this line i get error
    ++v;
}
```

ALWAYS y==0 and x==1 and ++v is executed as a infinity loop
v=1,2,3,......200 and crash

Comment: a goes until 100 so x changes continuously. For example, if a=9 x will be 4 y will be 1 and a wil remain same as 9.

Comment: i am sure that a=x is doing always, and then for bucle starts on 1 always ;-)

Comment: Put  Log.i("x y a", "-----" + x + " " + y + " " + a);   after while(y==0 && x!=1);

Comment: We tried to execute this code with python and it worked well. Output was correct. I dont get what is problem with java.

Comment: you are changing a variable at same value and it is the for variable, what do you want to do?

Comment: I realized that you are right. A starts with 2 and then it is changed to 1 and again be 2 because of for loop and so on. Idid some modification on the code and now it works. Thanks for showing error.

Comment: I just changed all a with s and all s with a from the begining of the first do-while.

Comment: I was trying to solve that question from codility web site.

Comment: Set  S consists of  numbers of the form 2^P *2^Q  where P  and Q are nonnegative integers.Sequence Acontains the elements of set S in ascending order. The first few elemens of A are: A[0]=1,A[1]=2,A[2]=3,A[3]=4,A[4]=6,A[5]=8,A[6]=9,A[7]=12                        write a function : int solution (int N) that, given a non-negative integer N,returns the value A[N]. For example given N=4 the function should return 6

Comment: public int solution(int N) {
        if (N == 0) return 1;

        double p = (-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 4*N*2))/2;
        int P = (int)Math.ceil(p)  - 1;
        int Q = N - P*(P+1)/2 - 1;

        return (int) (Math.pow(2, P) + Math.pow(2, Q));
    }

Comment: Your code seems so short but it is not working correctly. For example, if you give 11 as a parameter to method solution the output is  17 and that is not form of 2^P *2^Q.

Comment: 2^4 + 2^0 = 16 + 1 = 17

Comment: I am sorry. Again i am wrong because the form of number should be like that  (2^P )* (3^Q). And  there is a multiplication between two parenthesis not addition, this is your mistake.

Comment: Last chance :-)     public int solution(int N) {

        if (N == 0) return 1; 
        double p = (-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 4*N*2))/2; 
        int P = (int)Math.ceil(p) - 1;
        int Q = N - P*(P+1)/2 - 1;
        return (int) (Math.pow(2, P) * Math.pow(3, Q)); 
    }

Comment: No it is not working correct. Just try it in your platform. It gives wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your code is supposed to do, but you have to check somewhere if `l` exceeds the size of `ary`.
One solution could be

```
for(int a = 2; a < 100 && l < ary.length; a ++) {
    ...
}
```

while another solution could be

```
 if(y == 0 && x == 1 && l < ary.length) {
     ary[l] = s; // line where your error occurs
     ++ l;
 }
```

The error on `System.out.print(obs.find(10));` only occurs because `find()` throws an exception.

Comment: This will not help, then the code goes into infinite loop. for value a = 2. because the value of a is update in the do-while loop.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean?

Comment: Did you try running this code, after making the suggest change?